Python OpenGL error, "buffer cannot be empty"
I have an issue loading multiple .obj model in Python ModernGL.
It output this error: "_moderngl.Error: the buffer cannot be empty"
more exactly it gives this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\---\PycharmProjects\Things\main.py", line 71, in <module>
    app = GraphicsEngine()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\---\PycharmProjects\Things\main.py", line 39, in __init__
    self.mesh = Mesh(self)
                ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\---\PycharmProjects\Things\mesh.py", line 8, in __init__
    self.vao = VAO(app.ctx)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\---\PycharmProjects\Things\vao.py", line 8, in __init__
    self.vbo = VBO(ctx)
               ^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\---\PycharmProjects\Things\vbo.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.vbos['corbeau'] = CorbeauVBO(ctx)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\---\PycharmProjects\Things\vbo.py", line 97, in __init__
    super().__init__(app)
  File "C:\Users\---\PycharmProjects\Things\vbo.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.vbo = self.get_vbo()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\---\PycharmProjects\Things\vbo.py", line 29, in get_vbo
    vbo = self.ctx.buffer(vertex_data)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\---\PycharmProjects\Things\.venv\Lib\site-packages\moderngl\__init__.py", line 1795, in buffer
    res.mglo, res._size, res._glo = self.mglo.buffer(data, reserve, dynamic)
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_moderngl.Error: the buffer cannot be empty

The error occurs at line 29 in the vbo.py file: vbo = self.ctx.buffer(vertex_data) when loading the CorbeauVBO get_vertex_data function.
It is loading the first .obj file correctly, but not the Corbeau.obj file.
If you need others pieces of code or other information, ask me.
Line 28: print(f"get vbo = {vertex_data}") returns:
get vbo = [[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1. -1. -1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  1. -1.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1. -1. -1.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1. -1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1. -1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1. -1.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1. -1.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1. -1. -1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1. -1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0. -1.  1. -1. -1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0. -1. -1. -1. -1.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0. -1. -1.  1. -1.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0. -1. -1.  1. -1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0. -1.  1.  1. -1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0. -1.  1. -1. -1.]
 [ 1.  1. -1.  0.  0. -1.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  1. -1.  0.  0. -1.  1. -1.]
 [ 0.  0. -1.  0.  0. -1. -1. -1.]
 [ 1.  1. -1.  0.  0. -1.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  0. -1.  0.  0. -1. -1. -1.]
 [ 1.  0. -1.  0.  0. -1. -1.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0. -1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1. -1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  1.  0. -1.  1. -1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0. -1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1. -1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0. -1.  0. -1. -1.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0. -1.  0.  1. -1. -1.]
 [ 1.  1.  0. -1.  0.  1. -1.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0. -1.  0. -1. -1.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. -1.  0. -1. -1. -1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0. -1.  0.  1. -1. -1.]]

for the first file, but get vbo = [] for the Corbeau.obj file.
in fact, line 104 print(f"obj corbo = {obj}") returns:
obj corbo = <pywavefront.material.Material object at 0x00000241FE966D80>
but line 107 print(f"vertex_corbo = {vertex_data}") returns: vertex_corbo = []
I'm French. So, sorry if I make errors or if I don't understand what you say.
Here is my code:
vbo.py file:
import numpy as np
import moderngl as mgl
import pywavefront


class VBO:
    def __init__(self, ctx):
        self.vbos = {}
        self.vbos['cube'] = CubeVBO(ctx)
        self.vbos['cat'] = CatVBO(ctx)
        self.vbos['corbeau'] = CorbeauVBO(ctx)

    def destroy(self):
        [vbo.destroy() for vbo in self.vbos.values()]

class BaseVBO:
    def __init__(self, ctx):

        self.ctx = ctx
        self.vbo = self.get_vbo()
        self.format: str = None
        self.attribs: list = None

    def get_vertex_data(self): ...

    def get_vbo(self):
        vertex_data = self.get_vertex_data()
        print(f"get vbo = {vertex_data}")
        vbo = self.ctx.buffer(vertex_data)
        return vbo

    def destroy(self):
        self.vbo.release()


class CubeVBO(BaseVBO):
    def __init__(self, ctx):
        super().__init__(ctx)
        self.format = '2f 3f 3f'
        self.attribs = ['in_texcoord_0', 'in_normal', 'in_position']

    @staticmethod
    def get_data(vertices, indices):
        data = [vertices[ind] for triangle in indices for ind in triangle]
        return np.array(data, dtype='f4')

    def get_vertex_data(self):
        vertices = [(-1, -1, 1), ( 1, -1,  1), (1,  1,  1), (-1, 1,  1),
                    (-1, 1, -1), (-1, -1, -1), (1, -1, -1), ( 1, 1, -1)]

        indices = [(0, 2, 3), (0, 1, 2),
                   (1, 7, 2), (1, 6, 7),
                   (6, 5, 4), (4, 7, 6),
                   (3, 4, 5), (3, 5, 0),
                   (3, 7, 4), (3, 2, 7),
                   (0, 6, 1), (0, 5, 6)]
        vertex_data = self.get_data(vertices, indices)

        tex_coord_vertices = [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)]
        tex_coord_indices = [(0, 2, 3), (0, 1, 2),
                             (0, 2, 3), (0, 1, 2),
                             (0, 1, 2), (2, 3, 0),
                             (2, 3, 0), (2, 0, 1),
                             (0, 2, 3), (0, 1, 2),
                             (3, 1, 2), (3, 0, 1),]
        tex_coord_data = self.get_data(tex_coord_vertices, tex_coord_indices)

        normals = [( 0, 0, 1) * 6,
                   ( 1, 0, 0) * 6,
                   ( 0, 0,-1) * 6,
                   (-1, 0, 0) * 6,
                   ( 0, 1, 0) * 6,
                   ( 0,-1, 0) * 6,]
        normals = np.array(normals, dtype='f4').reshape(36, 3)

        vertex_data = np.hstack([normals, vertex_data])
        vertex_data = np.hstack([tex_coord_data, vertex_data])
        return vertex_data


class CatVBO(BaseVBO):
    def __init__(self, app):
        super().__init__(app)
        self.format = '2f 3f 3f'
        self.attribs = ['in_texcoord_0', 'in_normal', 'in_position']

    def get_vertex_data(self):
        objs = pywavefront.Wavefront('objects/cat/20430_Cat_v1_NEW.obj', cache=True, parse=True)
        obj = objs.materials.popitem()[1]
        vertex_data = obj.vertices
        vertex_data = np.array(vertex_data, dtype='f4')
        print(f"vertex_cat = {vertex_data}")
        return vertex_data

class CorbeauVBO(BaseVBO):
    def __init__(self, app):
        super().__init__(app)
        self.format = '2f 3f 3f'
        self.attribs = ['in_texcoord_0', 'in_normal', 'in_position']

    def get_vertex_data(self):
        objs = pywavefront.Wavefront('objects/corbeau/Corbeau.obj', cache=True, parse=True)
        obj = objs.materials.popitem()[1]
        print(f"obj corbo = {obj}")
        vertex_data = obj.vertices
        vertex_data = np.array(vertex_data, dtype='f4')
        print(f"vertex_corbo = {vertex_data}")
        return vertex_data

Corbeau.obj file:
# Made in Blockbench 4.11.2
mtllib materials.mtl

v 0.0625 0.46875 -0.125
v 0.0625 0.46875 -0.25
v 0.0625 0.34375 -0.125
v 0.0625 0.34375 -0.25
v -0.0625 0.46875 -0.25
v -0.0625 0.46875 -0.125
v -0.0625 0.34375 -0.25
v -0.0625 0.34375 -0.125
v 0.03125 0.43047740375814125 -0.13164782973977465
v 0.03125 0.37670461285023066 -0.20844333389186762
v 0.03125 0.27688639545395527 -0.02410224792395351
v 0.03125 0.22311360454604473 -0.10089775207604648
v -0.03125 0.37670461285023066 -0.20844333389186762
v -0.03125 0.43047740375814125 -0.13164782973977465
v -0.03125 0.22311360454604473 -0.10089775207604648
v -0.03125 0.27688639545395527 -0.02410224792395351
v 0.03125 0.421875 -0.25
v 0.03125 0.421875 -0.34375
v 0.03125 0.359375 -0.25
v 0.03125 0.359375 -0.34375
v -0.03125 0.421875 -0.34375
v -0.03125 0.421875 -0.25
v -0.03125 0.359375 -0.34375
v -0.03125 0.359375 -0.25
v 0.03125 0.33838834764831843 0.36427669529663687
v 0.03125 0.42677669529663687 0.2758883476483185
v 0.03125 0.20580582617584078 0.23169417382415922
v 0.03125 0.29419417382415924 0.14330582617584078
v -0.03125 0.42677669529663687 0.2758883476483185
v -0.03125 0.33838834764831843 0.36427669529663687
v -0.03125 0.29419417382415924 0.14330582617584078
v -0.03125 0.20580582617584078 0.23169417382415922
v 0.09375 0.3125 0.25
v 0.09375 0.3125 -0.125
v 0.09375 0.125 0.25
v 0.09375 0.125 -0.125
v -0.09375 0.3125 -0.125
v -0.09375 0.3125 0.25
v -0.09375 0.125 -0.125
v -0.09375 0.125 0.25
v 0.20634440556392142 0.19529359435447446 0.125
v 0.20634440556392142 0.19529359435447446 -0.03125
v 0.18732061090739888 0.17050130247037337 0.125
v 0.18732061090739888 0.17050130247037337 -0.03125
v 0.05759065425931482 0.3094363622936096 -0.03125
v 0.05759065425931482 0.3094363622936096 0.125
v 0.0385668596027923 0.2846440704095085 -0.03125
v 0.0385668596027923 0.2846440704095085 0.125
vt 0.125 0.625
vt 0.1875 0.625
vt 0.1875 0.5625
vt 0.125 0.5625
vt 0.1875 0.625
vt 0.25 0.625
vt 0.25 0.5625
vt 0.1875 0.5625
vt 0.375 0.8125
vt 0.4375 0.8125
vt 0.4375 0.75
vt 0.375 0.75
vt 0.25 0.625
vt 0.3125 0.625
vt 0.3125 0.5625
vt 0.25 0.5625
vt 0.4375 0.6875
vt 0.375 0.6875
vt 0.375 0.75
vt 0.4375 0.75
vt 0.375 0.625
vt 0.3125 0.625
vt 0.3125 0.5625
vt 0.375 0.5625
vn 0 0 -1
vn 1 0 0
vn 0 0 1
vn -1 0 0
vn 0 1 0
vn 0 -1 0
f 4/4/1 7/3/1 5/2/1 2/1/1
f 3/8/2 4/7/2 2/6/2 1/5/2
f 8/12/3 3/11/3 1/10/3 6/9/3
f 7/16/4 8/15/4 6/14/4 5/13/4
f 6/20/5 1/19/5 2/18/5 5/17/5
f 7/24/6 4/23/6 3/22/6 8/21/6
vt 0.375 0.59375
vt 0.40625 0.59375
vt 0.40625 0.5
vt 0.375 0.5
vt 0.0625 0.625
vt 0.109375 0.625
vt 0.109375 0.53125
vt 0.0625 0.53125
vt 0.40625 0.59375
vt 0.4375 0.59375
vt 0.4375 0.5
vt 0.40625 0.5
vt 0.375 0.90625
vt 0.421875 0.90625
vt 0.421875 0.8125
vt 0.375 0.8125
vt 0.46875 0.671875
vt 0.4375 0.671875
vt 0.4375 0.71875
vt 0.46875 0.71875
vt 0.34375 0.5625
vt 0.3125 0.5625
vt 0.3125 0.515625
vt 0.34375 0.515625
vn 0 -0.573576436351046 -0.8191520442889918
vn 1 0 0
vn 0 0.573576436351046 0.8191520442889918
vn -1 0 0
vn 0 0.8191520442889918 -0.573576436351046
vn 0 -0.8191520442889918 0.573576436351046
f 12/28/7 15/27/7 13/26/7 10/25/7
f 11/32/8 12/31/8 10/30/8 9/29/8
f 16/36/9 11/35/9 9/34/9 14/33/9
f 15/40/10 16/39/10 14/38/10 13/37/10
f 14/44/11 9/43/11 10/42/11 13/41/11
f 15/48/12 12/47/12 11/46/12 16/45/12
vt 0.21875 0.53125
vt 0.25 0.53125
vt 0.25 0.5
vt 0.21875 0.5
vt 0.4375 0.65625
vt 0.484375 0.65625
vt 0.484375 0.625
vt 0.4375 0.625
vt 0.25 0.53125
vt 0.28125 0.53125
vt 0.28125 0.5
vt 0.25 0.5
vt 0.4375 0.625
vt 0.484375 0.625
vt 0.484375 0.59375
vt 0.4375 0.59375
vt 0.375 0.515625
vt 0.34375 0.515625
vt 0.34375 0.5625
vt 0.375 0.5625
vt 0.46875 0.59375
vt 0.4375 0.59375
vt 0.4375 0.546875
vt 0.46875 0.546875
vn 0 0 -1
vn 1 0 0
vn 0 0 1
vn -1 0 0
vn 0 1 0
vn 0 -1 0
f 20/52/13 23/51/13 21/50/13 18/49/13
f 19/56/14 20/55/14 18/54/14 17/53/14
f 24/60/15 19/59/15 17/58/15 22/57/15
f 23/64/16 24/63/16 22/62/16 21/61/16
f 22/68/17 17/67/17 18/66/17 21/65/17
f 23/72/18 20/71/18 19/70/18 24/69/18
vt 0.375 0.6875
vt 0.40625 0.6875
vt 0.40625 0.59375
vt 0.375 0.59375
vt 0 0.625
vt 0.0625 0.625
vt 0.0625 0.53125
vt 0 0.53125
vt 0.40625 0.6875
vt 0.4375 0.6875
vt 0.4375 0.59375
vt 0.40625 0.59375
vt 0.375 1
vt 0.4375 1
vt 0.4375 0.90625
vt 0.375 0.90625
vt 0.1875 0.5
vt 0.15625 0.5
vt 0.15625 0.5625
vt 0.1875 0.5625
vt 0.21875 0.5625
vt 0.1875 0.5625
vt 0.1875 0.5
vt 0.21875 0.5
vn 0 0.7071067811865476 -0.7071067811865475
vn 1 0 0
vn 0 -0.7071067811865476 0.7071067811865475
vn -1 0 0
vn 0 0.7071067811865475 0.7071067811865476
vn 0 -0.7071067811865475 -0.7071067811865476
f 28/76/19 31/75/19 29/74/19 26/73/19
f 27/80/20 28/79/20 26/78/20 25/77/20
f 32/84/21 27/83/21 25/82/21 30/81/21
f 31/88/22 32/87/22 30/86/22 29/85/22
f 30/92/23 25/91/23 26/90/23 29/89/23
f 31/96/24 28/95/24 27/94/24 32/93/24
vt 0.25 1
vt 0.375 1
vt 0.375 0.90625
vt 0.25 0.90625
vt 0 0.8125
vt 0.1875 0.8125
vt 0.1875 0.71875
vt 0 0.71875
vt 0.25 0.90625
vt 0.375 0.90625
vt 0.375 0.8125
vt 0.25 0.8125
vt 0.1875 0.8125
vt 0.375 0.8125
vt 0.375 0.71875
vt 0.1875 0.71875
vt 0.125 0.8125
vt 0 0.8125
vt 0 1
vt 0.125 1
vt 0.25 1
vt 0.125 1
vt 0.125 0.8125
vt 0.25 0.8125
vn 0 0 -1
vn 1 0 0
vn 0 0 1
vn -1 0 0
vn 0 1 0
vn 0 -1 0
f 36/100/25 39/99/25 37/98/25 34/97/25
f 35/104/26 36/103/26 34/102/26 33/101/26
f 40/108/27 35/107/27 33/106/27 38/105/27
f 39/112/28 40/111/28 38/110/28 37/109/28
f 38/116/29 33/115/29 34/114/29 37/113/29
f 39/120/30 36/119/30 35/118/30 40/117/30
vt 0.4375 0.8125
vt 0.53125 0.8125
vt 0.53125 0.796875
vt 0.4375 0.796875
vt 0 0.53125
vt 0.078125 0.53125
vt 0.078125 0.515625
vt 0 0.515625
vt 0.21875 0.5625
vt 0.3125 0.5625
vt 0.3125 0.546875
vt 0.21875 0.546875
vt 0.46875 1
vt 0.546875 1
vt 0.546875 0.984375
vt 0.46875 0.984375
vt 0.09375 0.640625
vt 0 0.640625
vt 0 0.71875
vt 0.09375 0.71875
vt 0.1875 0.71875
vt 0.09375 0.71875
vt 0.09375 0.640625
vt 0.1875 0.640625
vn 0 0 -1
vn 0.7933533402912352 -0.6087614290087207 0
vn 0 0 1
vn -0.7933533402912352 0.6087614290087207 0
vn 0.6087614290087207 0.7933533402912352 0
vn -0.6087614290087207 -0.7933533402912352 0
f 44/124/31 47/123/31 45/122/31 42/121/31
f 43/128/32 44/127/32 42/126/32 41/125/32
f 48/132/33 43/131/33 41/130/33 46/129/33
f 47/136/34 48/135/34 46/134/34 45/133/34
f 46/140/35 41/139/35 42/138/35 45/137/35
f 47/144/36 44/143/36 43/142/36 48/141/36
v -0.05759065425931482 0.3094363622936096 0.125
v -0.05759065425931482 0.3094363622936096 -0.03125
v -0.0385668596027923 0.2846440704095085 0.125
v -0.0385668596027923 0.2846440704095085 -0.03125
v -0.20634440556392142 0.19529359435447446 -0.03125
v -0.20634440556392142 0.19529359435447446 0.125
v -0.18732061090739888 0.17050130247037337 -0.03125
v -0.18732061090739888 0.17050130247037337 0.125
vt 0.4375 0.78125
vt 0.53125 0.78125
vt 0.53125 0.765625
vt 0.4375 0.765625
vt 0.46875 0.96875
vt 0.546875 0.96875
vt 0.546875 0.953125
vt 0.46875 0.953125
vt 0.4375 0.75
vt 0.53125 0.75
vt 0.53125 0.734375
vt 0.4375 0.734375
vt 0.46875 0.9375
vt 0.546875 0.9375
vt 0.546875 0.921875
vt 0.46875 0.921875
vt 0.28125 0.640625
vt 0.1875 0.640625
vt 0.1875 0.71875
vt 0.28125 0.71875
vt 0.375 0.71875
vt 0.28125 0.71875
vt 0.28125 0.640625
vt 0.375 0.640625
vn 0 0 -1
vn 0.7933533402912352 0.6087614290087207 0
vn 0 0 1
vn -0.7933533402912352 -0.6087614290087207 0
vn -0.6087614290087207 0.7933533402912352 0
vn 0.6087614290087207 -0.7933533402912352 0
f 52/148/37 55/147/37 53/146/37 50/145/37
f 51/152/38 52/151/38 50/150/38 49/149/38
f 56/156/39 51/155/39 49/154/39 54/153/39
f 55/160/40 56/159/40 54/158/40 53/157/40
f 54/164/41 49/163/41 50/162/41 53/161/41
f 55/168/42 52/167/42 51/166/42 56/165/42
v -0.03125 0.125 0.06312499999999999
v -0.03125 0.125 0.06249999999999999
v -0.03125 0 0.06312499999999999
v -0.03125 0 0.06249999999999999
v -0.09375 0.125 0.06249999999999999
v -0.09375 0.125 0.06312499999999999
v -0.09375 0 0.06249999999999999
v -0.09375 0 0.06312499999999999
vt 0.125 0.5625
vt 0.15625 0.5625
vt 0.15625 0.5
vt 0.125 0.5
vt 0 1
vt 0 1
vt 0 0.9375
vt 0 0.9375
vt 0.4375 0.875
vt 0.46875 0.875
vt 0.46875 0.8125
vt 0.4375 0.8125
vt 0 1
vt 0 1
vt 0 0.9375
vt 0 0.9375
vt 0.03125 1
vt 0 1
vt 0 1
vt 0.03125 1
vt 0.03125 1
vt 0 1
vt 0 1
vt 0.03125 1
vn 0 0 -1
vn 1 0 0
vn 0 0 1
vn -1 0 0
vn 0 1 0
vn 0 -1 0
f 60/172/43 63/171/43 61/170/43 58/169/43
f 59/176/44 60/175/44 58/174/44 57/173/44
f 64/180/45 59/179/45 57/178/45 62/177/45
f 63/184/46 64/183/46 62/182/46 61/181/46
f 62/188/47 57/187/47 58/186/47 61/185/47
f 63/192/48 60/191/48 59/190/48 64/189/48
v -0.03125 0.000625 0.0625
v -0.03125 0.000625 0
v -0.03125 0 0.0625
v -0.03125 0 0
v -0.09375 0.000625 0
v -0.09375 0.000625 0.0625
v -0.09375 0 0
v -0.09375 0 0.0625
vt 0 1
vt 0.03125 1
vt 0.03125 1
vt 0 1
vt 0 1
vt 0.03125 1
vt 0.03125 1
vt 0 1
vt 0 1
vt 0.03125 1
vt 0.03125 1
vt 0 1
vt 0 1
vt 0.03125 1
vt 0.03125 1
vt 0 1
vt 0.5 0.84375
vt 0.46875 0.84375
vt 0.46875 0.875
vt 0.5 0.875
vt 0.5 0.84375
vt 0.46875 0.84375
vt 0.46875 0.8125
vt 0.5 0.8125
vn 0 0 -1
vn 1 0 0
vn 0 0 1
vn -1 0 0
vn 0 1 0
vn 0 -1 0
f 68/196/49 71/195/49 69/194/49 66/193/49
f 67/200/50 68/199/50 66/198/50 65/197/50
f 72/204/51 67/203/51 65/202/51 70/201/51
f 71/208/52 72/207/52 70/206/52 69/205/52
f 70/212/53 65/211/53 66/210/53 69/209/53
f 71/216/54 68/215/54 67/214/54 72/213/54
v 0.09375 0.125 0.06312499999999999
v 0.09375 0.125 0.06249999999999999
v 0.09375 0 0.06312499999999999
v 0.09375 0 0.06249999999999999
v 0.03125 0.125 0.06249999999999999
v 0.03125 0.125 0.06312499999999999
v 0.03125 0 0.06249999999999999
v 0.03125 0 0.06312499999999999
vt 0.4375 1
vt 0.46875 1
vt 0.46875 0.9375
vt 0.4375 0.9375
vt 0 1
vt 0 1
vt 0 0.9375
vt 0 0.9375
vt 0.4375 0.9375
vt 0.46875 0.9375
vt 0.46875 0.875
vt 0.4375 0.875
vt 0 1
vt 0 1
vt 0 0.9375
vt 0 0.9375
vt 0.03125 1
vt 0 1
vt 0 1
vt 0.03125 1
vt 0.03125 1
vt 0 1
vt 0 1
vt 0.03125 1
vn 0 0 -1
vn 1 0 0
vn 0 0 1
vn -1 0 0
vn 0 1 0
vn 0 -1 0
f 76/220/55 79/219/55 77/218/55 74/217/55
f 75/224/56 76/223/56 74/222/56 73/221/56
f 80/228/57 75/227/57 73/226/57 78/225/57
f 79/232/58 80/231/58 78/230/58 77/229/58
f 78/236/59 73/235/59 74/234/59 77/233/59
f 79/240/60 76/239/60 75/238/60 80/237/60
v 0.09375 0.000625 0.0625
v 0.09375 0.000625 0
v 0.09375 0 0.0625
v 0.09375 0 0
v 0.03125 0.000625 0
v 0.03125 0.000625 0.0625
v 0.03125 0 0
v 0.03125 0 0.0625
vt 0 1
vt 0.03125 1
vt 0.03125 1
vt 0 1
vt 0 1
vt 0.03125 1
vt 0.03125 1
vt 0 1
vt 0 1
vt 0.03125 1
vt 0.03125 1
vt 0 1
vt 0 1
vt 0.03125 1
vt 0.03125 1
vt 0 1
vt 0.125 0.5
vt 0.09375 0.5
vt 0.09375 0.53125
vt 0.125 0.53125
vt 0.5 0.90625
vt 0.46875 0.90625
vt 0.46875 0.875
vt 0.5 0.875
vn 0 0 -1
vn 1 0 0
vn 0 0 1
vn -1 0 0
vn 0 1 0
vn 0 -1 0
f 84/244/61 87/243/61 85/242/61 82/241/61
f 83/248/62 84/247/62 82/246/62 81/245/62
f 88/252/63 83/251/63 81/250/63 86/249/63
f 87/256/64 88/255/64 86/254/64 85/253/64
f 86/260/65 81/259/65 82/258/65 85/257/65
f 87/264/66 84/263/66 83/262/66 88/261/66

Can someone help me fix this error ?

If I take your data, place it in a file named Corbeau.obj and comment out the mtllib materials.mtl line (because I don't have that file), I can read the file data -- vertices etc. -- just fine using objs = pywavefront.Wavefront('Corbeau.obj', cache=True, parse=True).  That being the case, my guess would be that you're not reading the file you think you are.  Try setting cache=False and strict=True in the pywavefront.Wavefront call.  Also try adding some nonsense text to the end of the file you think you're reading to see if it makes any difference.

What do you mean by "you're not reading the file you think you are." ?

Try this: change the pywavefront.Wavefront('objects/corbeau/Corbeau.obj', ... call in your code to objs = pywavefront.Wavefront('objects/corbeau/Corbeau.obj', strict=True, cache=False, parse=True).  Then open objects/corbeau/Corbeau.obj in your text editor, add some random text at the end and save the file.  Does that generate any errors when you run your application?

Yes it does generate an error in pywavefront. Not the same as the previous one though. It's too long to fit in a comment.

Last line is: File "C:\Users\---\PycharmProjects\Things\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pywavefront\parser.py", line 144, in parse_fallback     raise PywavefrontException("Unimplemented OBJ format statement '%s' on line '%s'" pywavefront.exceptions.PywavefrontException: Unimplemented OBJ format statement 'ziypaeh' on line 'ziypaeh hzéebdh p'

In parallel, I did some more research, and I found this website: https://products.aspose.app/3d/conversion/obj-to-obj I converted my .obj file, it game me another .obj file, but It works for some reason (with the new one), and I don't even know why.
